# ¿Cuál es la manera correcta de crear una tabla 'Documentos Adjuntos' (attachments) en Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Quisiera crear una tabla `'attachments'` donde se guardarán documentos adjuntos (pdf, imagenes, txt, etc.) de otras clases (`user`, `family_group`, `academic_training`, etc.)

¿Es recomendable hacer esto, o tener una tabla `'attachments_user'`, `'attachments_family_group'` y asi por cada clase?

Actualmente tengo creada una tabla para documentos adjuntos, y estoy usando la gema `carrierwave`.

Answer (score 1):

Mas que clasificar por modelo que tiene asociado un adjunto (que puede ser válido dadas las circunstancias), la idea es clasificar por la naturaleza del adjunto (Llamado `Uploader` en carrierwave) y del problema mismo que quieras resolver. Por ejemplo:

- Podrías tener una tabla `users` que tenga un avatar asociado. Para este caso ni siquiera es necesario crear una tabla, solo el campo en la tabla de usuarios y un uploader de carrierwave.
- Ahora a este mismo modelo de usuarios se quiere que tenga una galería de imágenes asociada a su perfil. Para esto claramente necesitarías que el usuario tenga una relación `has_many :images` y una tabla `images` con un campo `file`, por poner algún nombre, que será administrado por el uploader.
- Siguiendo con el mismo ejemplo, se decide que ahora el usuario podrá asociar documentos además de imágenes. Una opción podría ser simplemente crear una relación `has_many :attachments` con una nueva tabla donde vaya cualquier tipo de archivo, tanto documentos como imágenes. Esto funcionaría sin problemas, sin embargo las validaciones de imágenes son distintas a las de documentos. Por ejemplo validar la extensión de los archivos, el tamaño máximo o hasta validar las dimensiones de una imagen o realizar postprocesado como resize/cropping, lo cual no tiene ningún sentido realizar en un documento. Para este caso valdría la pena hacer dos relaciones  `has_many :images` y  `has_many :documents` cada una con sus respectivas tabla y uploaders `ImageUploader` y `DocumentUploader` los cuales tendrán las reglas que hayas definido para cada tipo de archivo.
- Ahora se da el caso que tienes tanto la imagen de avatar del usuario como las imágenes de la galería y ambas usando el mismo `ImageUploader` ya que ambos adjuntos son imágenes, sin embargo para la imagen del avatar quieres crear una versión más pequeña en dimensiones (thumb) del mismo archivo para que pueda ser usado en distintas partes de tu página y para las galerías quieres que solo sean adjuntas imágenes en formato jpg para luego realizar un crop de la imagen y dejarla como un cuadrado para que se muestre en la galería en sí. Para resolver esto, necesitarías crear dos uploaders, un `AvatarUploader` y un `GalleryImageUploader` cada uno con sus reglas establecidas.

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido solucionar de manera optima usando asociaciones polimorficas.
https://launchschool.com/blog/understanding-polymorphic-associations-in-rails